# Confusing results with git --git-dir and --work-tree

Tags: git

Running the following:

```
git init --bare bare
git init not-bare
pushd not-bare
echo something > file
git add file
git commit -m something
git remote add bare ../bare
git push bare master
rm -rf .git
popd
git --work-tree=not-bare --git-dir=bare status
```

gives me the following output:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    file

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    file
```

This is confusing to me. I would have expected that, given that the contents of the work tree (`not-bare`) match exactly the "expected" contents at that commit, the command would return empty, indicating an unchanged status.

Can anyone explain why I am getting the results I do?

Comment: Why are you running init twice? Why are you creating a bare repo, and a normal repo, in the same directory?

Comment: @evolutionxbox this is just a minimal reproduction to illustrate this. Where I first found it was checking changes between a deployed site and the bare repo on the same server.

Comment: I think what confuses me is that a bare repo doesn't have a working tree.

Comment: @evolutionxbox it’s a different way of thinking about git repos that’s for sure.

Comment: What do you mean? Different way of thinking? They're useful for storing a repo, but not for working in...

Comment: I may have misunderstood your comment @evolutionxbox, were you talking about a bare repo not having a working tree in general, or in this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about what @evolutionxbox had said in comments I went back to the man pages and found the following from `man git-status`:

```
Displays paths that have differences between the index file and the current HEAD
commit, paths that have differences between the working tree and the index file,
and paths in the working tree that are not tracked by Git (and are not ignored by
gitignore(5)).
```

So looking through the files in both `bare` and the deleted `not-bare/.git`, I find one file that is missing in the bare repo, the `index`, as referred to in the man page.

This all makes sense now, as `ls-files` differs between the two git directories:

```
git --git-dir=bare ls-files
# no output
git --git-dir=not-bare/.git ls-files
file
```

So in summary, `git status` can't make sense of what I'm asking it to do, as the specified `git-dir` is a bare repo, which, in addition to not having a work tree, also doesn't have a corresponding index.

Comment: Actually, a bare Git repository *does* have an index, due to a sort of weird implementation choice of how to name the index and work-tree. Index files and work-trees come in pairs, so *logically* there should be no index for a bare repository since it has no work-tree, but it still has the ability to keep a file named `bare.git/index` (assuming the repository is named `bare.git`). The index gets created on demand, though, so until you do something that forces it to exist, it won't exist *yet*.

Comment: @torek ah, I see. In either case, it does seem tricky to easily cause the index to be created, without having to use plumbing commands.

Comment: The easiest way is with `git --work-tree=path/to/existing/dir checkout ...`. This populates the supplied work-tree, using (creating if necessary) the index. This index now indexes `path/to/existing/dir`. If you do `git --work-tree=different/path op`, Git can use the index for `path/to/existing-dir` and hence do the wrong thing! This is, to put it mildly, not a great situation.